# what does that mean Must be something in the air?

Tags: phrases

a full sentence is here. speaker A : I can't believe that i'm pregnant again. must be something in the air. speaker B : your legs

what does that mean "must be something in the air" A dictionary says that the phrase refers to someone's having a crush on sb, or something bad, good, feeling that coming something to happen without talking, or rumor is around people, or they are having the same feeling. can you know that? please help me

Comment: It's a joke. Yes, [*something in the air*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/something-is-in-the-air) is used for saying that people have a similar feeling, that something exciting or new is happening, or that an unknown factor is at work, but the pay-off is that her legs really were in the air.

Comment: What research have you done? It's a common-enough expression so you should be able to find help on Google.

Comment: One might say, of a couple that had a large number of children, or a cluster of these, that there must be 'something in the water'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I like the collective "cluster of children".

Comment: Ironically enough, it's the infection metaphor. 'It's catching!' / 'It must be catching' is another way of phrasing it. //// It's often said in a rather rueful way, 'Why does it always happen to me!' 'It's not _my_ fault.'